# Custom tooltip positioning

Tags: javascript, heatmap, plotly

I'm facing issues to properly position a custom tooltip on a Plotly.js heatmap.

I'm using the l2p method (what's this acronym standing for?) in combination with the pointNumber data to get a relative positioning within the heatmap. It looks like:

```
x: point.xaxis.l2p(point.pointNumber[1]),
y: point.yaxis.l2p(point.pointNumber[0])
```

But the problem with that is that it is relative to the top/left origin of the heatmap svg itself without the outer x- and y-axis labels, so I'm actually missing that part and wonder about whether there isn't a built-in functionality to get this positioning information directly? The problem by using external divs as tooltip area is that they are located completely outside of the chart and with that I need the information with reference to the top/left origin outside of the chart and the axis labeling.

What seems to work is to use the axis private _offset property and add it to the x and y positions above, so I get

```
x: point.xaxis.l2p(point.pointNumber[1]) + point.xaxis._offset,
y: point.yaxis.l2p(point.pointNumber[0]) + point.yaxis._offset
```

But that looks quite nasty to me. Can someone point me to some documentation or demo on how to do that "the plotly way" esp. for the heatmap?

Answer (score 2):

You could use Javascript's [`pageX` and `pageY`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_pagex.asp) functions and combine them the with Plotly's hover event.

You can get the cursor position in absolute pixels and use it directly. In the snippet below a dot is moving together with the cursor when the mouse is above the Plotly `div`. Its size and color are determined by the data over which the cursor is located.

Of course you can bind the [`onmousemove`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp) event to any part of the plot as well and make something more sophisticated than just a dot.

```js
//create some random data
var data = [{z: [], type: 'heatmap'}];
var z = [];
 
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  z = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 10; j += 1) {
    z.push(Math.random());
  }
  data[0].z.push(z);
} 

var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var myPoint = document.getElementById('myPoint');
var colors = Plotly.d3.scale.category20();

//move the red dot
myPlot.onmousemove = function(event) {
  myPoint.style.left = event.pageX + "px";
  myPoint.style.top = event.pageY + "px";
}
myPlot.onmouseleave = function() {
  myPoint.style.left = "-999px";
  myPoint.style.top = "-999px";
}

//create the plot
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
//use Plotly's hover event to get the data
myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(data){
 myPoint.style.border = "solid " + (2 + (data.points[0].z * 5)) +"px " + colors(Math.abs(1 - data.points[0].z));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'>
</div>
<div id="myPoint" style="top: -999px; left: -999px; border: 5px solid #ff0000; border-radius: 50%; position: absolute; z-index: 999;">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Maximilian,

yes, I know about the pageX/Y event properties, but my point is the integration with the plotly data itself: How do you want to access now the underlying Plotly data you hovered over?

That's the reason I use the `plotly_hover` event because that's the purpose of that event, but unfortunately I cannot find any pageX/Y information in the response data which would solve the issue.

Comment: @andi1984: see the updated snippet. Now it uses both the data and the pageX/Y attributes.

Comment: Thx for your update. I can see your point to use mousemove to update the position and use the plotly internal one to work with the data. But quite honestly this approach looks like a fix around the Plotly API to make this possible. It is a way of doing it for sure but I would assume that I can do the same within that plotly event callback! So this is not the answer I thought about.

Nevertheless thx for the help and the answer! I will give you the bounty if it will be the only answer to my question within the next days.

Comment: How do we do this for plotly in python with dash?

Answer (score 2):

[One of the core developers of Plotly answered me to this question](https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-customize-plotly-tooltip/332/13?u=andi1984) that the way I calculate the position is currently the best way of doing it and thus this issue can be closed.

Comment: Do you know how to achieve this when not within a Plotly event? I'd like to get the x, y pixel values in order to simulate hovering but without an event handle.