# Plot.ly - How can I get exact x / y pixel coordinates of a marker / point?

Tags: javascript, svg, plotly

Right now, I'm struggling to convert the x and y axis position from a marker on a scatter graph to pixel position relative to the graph. My goal is to add an html element outside of the graph, and position it exactly above the point.

I checked this forum thread here: https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-customize-plotly-tooltip/332. There, I found about the `l2p()` function, which seems to help a lot. The returned x/y pixel coordinate seems to be on the right path, but there's a huge offset between the returned coordinate and the real coordinate of the point on the screen. Here's a quick demo:

http://codepen.io/diegoliv/pen/NdWKWj

(check the position of the red dot on the screen, it always has the same offset for both x / y axis).

I tried this code with several data sources, and seems that the offset varies for all of them.

So, I'm suspecting that the returned result from `l2p()` and similar functions (like `d2p()`) are not relative to the root svg element, but is relative to something else.

How can we calculate this offset so we can use it to calculate the exact x/y pixel coordinates on the graph for the red dot? OR, is there any other better approaches to get these coordinates?

Comment: Hi Diego,

I already answered you in the forum and I also posted a similar question (with a bounty) on Stackoverflow (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395959/custom-tooltip-positioning)

Comment: Perhaps this might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41453423/2776376